# Is $\hspace{10pt}$ equivalent to triple space?

Tags: spacing, overleaf, setspace

I am trying to write the abstract of my thesis and I need the space between the title and my name to be triple space and in the default abstract by overleaf they are using this command $\hspace{10pt},$ does this command equivalent to triple space?

**EDIT:**

Triple space means 2 blank lines between.

**EDIT:**

Here is the code I have:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[a4paper, vmargin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
   
    \newgeometry{top=1.75in, bottom=1in} 
    
    \pagenumbering{gobble}

\Large
 \begin{center}
ON CUP-PRODUCTS OF COFIBERS OF MOORE SPACES AND HOPF INVARIANCE\\

\hspace{10pt}

% Author names and affiliations
\large
Arthur Author$^1$, Cecilia CoAuthor$^2$ \\

\hspace{10pt}

\small  
$^1$) First affiliation\\
arthur.author@correspondence.email.com\\
$^2$) Second affiliation

\end{center}

\hspace{10pt}

\normalsize

This is a simple one-page abstract template. Please keep your abstract length at one page. The abstract should be in English. You may include figures and pictures in your abstract, as long as they fit in the single page limit.

Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur? (Cicero, 45 BCe)
    
    \newpage
    
    \restoregeometry % restores the geometry from the preamble
    \lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Since spaces vary from template to template there is no way to tell. Just use anything your classmates do.

Comment: Triple space denotes a relative *vertical* distance between lines of text, where "relative" means some multiple of a default amount (about which you've told us exactly nothing so far). Since `\hspace` inserts a fixed amount of *horizontal* whitespace, it cannot possibly be "equivalent to triple space". Please clarify your setup.

Comment: @Symbol1 I am the only one who is writing thesis in my class.

Comment: @Mico Triple space means 2 blank lines between as the guidelines document indicate.

Comment: @Mico I added my code .... I hope that is what you mean by asking me to clarify my setup.

Comment: This is the third or so question you have posted about that abstract page, you really don't need to use `\newgeometry` here it just complicates things for no apparent reason. You `\hspace` are adding invisible 10pt horizontal spaces in weird places??? and never end a paragraph with `\\ ` latex warns you about each of those, you should delete them. (actually it won't warn inside center but they are doing nothing, just delete them anyway)

Comment: @Happy - (I do happen to know what "triple space" means.) The main point of my earlier comment was that an `\hspace` directive -- the`h` in `\hspace` stands for **horizontal** -- cannot possibly be used to modify the **vertical** separation between lines. This point continues to apply.

Comment: you know, when I deleted the hspace{10pt} in my code I found that the space between the title and the author was deleted, even though this space is apparently vertical. I do not know why .... if you try the code you will see my point @Mico

Comment: @DavidCarlisle my abstract is part of the thesis, it is not the whole thesis, this is why I need newgeometry, because the margins of the thesis are different than the margins of the abstract.

Comment: @Mico I am guessing that horizontal space by 10 points means moving downward 2 vertical lines, which is the meaning of a triple space.

Comment: @Happy no you do not need newgeometry, here it complicates the processing and is not needed at all for this.  Why do you think you need a different geometry? You just need the abstract then force a page break, you arer setting the bottom margin with newgeometry but the bottom margin is never reached as you force a new page after the abstract.

Comment: @Happy - You wrote, "I am guessing that horizontal space by 10 points means moving downward 2 vertical lines". *Absolutely not!* You can verify this by replacing all 3 instances of `\hspace{10pt}` with `\null` (which is short for `\mbox{}`) and recompiling the test document: you'll still get the exact same vertical spacing between lines. Sorry, but the template you're using was evidently created by a near-incompetent who doesn't distinguish between `\hspace` ("insert horizontal space") and `\vspace` ("insert vertical space").

Comment: @Mico Ok, thank you for the correction :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not take thesis requirements too literally they often don't really make sense.

A normal inter-word space is a variable amount depending on the font used and the space required to justify the current paragraph.

You should not use math mode, so `\hspace{10pt}` not `$\hspace{10pt}$`.

If you are using the default Computer Modern font at 10pt, and the line is not shrunk or stretched to justify the text then the space between words is 3.33333pt so 10pt is 3 times that.

If you want to get the space of three spaces in the current font whatever the current font is, you could use

`xxx\ \ \ xxx`

Comment: But I just noticed @Mico's comment uder the question. It is possible that you mis-interpreted the instructions and a vertical space equivalent to three baselines was intended, in which case the answer to the question would be simply "no" and I'll delete this.

Comment: Is your answer above speaking about vertical spacing or horizontal spacing?

Comment: @Happy horizontal spacing which is what I took your question to mean as you asked about `\ `  **h** (orizontal)`space`  but you have edited the question so I woul delete this now as I said, but I can't as you accepted it:-)

Comment: you know, when I deleted the hspace{10pt} in my code I found that the space between the title and the author was deleted, even though this space is apparently vertical. I do not know why .... if you try the code you will see my point.

Comment: I am guessing that horizontal space by 10 points means moving downward 2 vertical lines, which is the meaning of a triple space.

Comment: @Happy no!!! it means moving to the right by 10pt  try typing `abc\hspace{10pt}xyz`  you will get 10pt _horizontal_ space between c and x on the same line. It is entirely the wrong command to make vertical space. Before you chnaged the question I thought you wanted `abc xyz` but with a space that was three times as big (which is more or less what `\hspace{10pt`} does)

Comment: @Happy you are just making a blank paragraph you would get the same from `\mbox{}` or `\hspace{1pt}` or `\hspace{200pt}`

Comment: Have you tested my code? BTW, it is a template of the abstract from overleaf.

Comment: yes and I don't know how I can explain more simply that `\hspace` is a command that adds horizontal space.  `\vspace` is the command to add vertical space.

Comment: Ok, I see. So if I need a triple space, should I use \vspace instead?

Comment: @Happy something like `\vspace{2\baselineskip}` will add the space normally taken by two lines of text

Comment: Sounds good. I think there is no need to delete your answer ..... because we have a healthy conversation below it.